# running an eclipse plugin without eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin

I have some code in an eclipse plugin and I would like to run this code without the need for eclipse. Is it possible?

It is possible to run the code from command line like the following:

```
eclipse.exe -console -data "WS_directory" -nosplash -application MyAppPluginID.MyAppExtensionID
```

However I still need the eclipse to be there on the machine which will run my code, and this is something I would like to avoid, but how?

Thanks, Anas

Comment: Do yo want to run java code for a plugin you have written to eclipse? In that case you can compile java code with command line.

Comment: You can build a RCP (Rich Client Program) which would contain all the parts of Eclipse needed to run your code.

Comment: @greg-449 : and then how can I run it? does it generate a jar file that I can call from command line through java? the eclipse plugin MyAppPluginID.MyAppExtensionID was a jar file created as an RCP, however, I can't call it as a standalone application since it is an eclipse plugin. Thanks

Comment: The RCP Product build produces an executable plus plugins like the Eclipse install.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Eclipse plugins (which are also OSGi Bundles) are not stand-alone applications, they need the Eclipse platform (and its OSGi runtime) in which to be hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console
```

and then

```
install <bundle URL> - Installs the bundle from the given URL
```

Source:
http://eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php

Comment: But this is like running eclipse! Isn't it? At the end, I would like to put my plugin code in a jar file to be used by some other java applications which are supposed to be a standalone applications, and they are not supposed to have eclipse. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This jar 1MB, so its not eclipse (>200MB), however this jar is the core of eclpise. Eclipse is just this jar with many plugins on top of it. If you are developing eclipse plugin, how come the client is not required to have eclipse.

Comment: I wrote my code in an eclipse plugin because it makes use of some other eclipse plugins. This code could be written without eclipse at all, but I wanted to make use of what already exists. The destination application, however, didn't require the code to be an an eclipse plugin. And definitly it will not be run through another jar file like 'org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar', but it should run through its own jar.

Comment: May be you need executable jar. You can export one from eclipse. Then you start it with java -jar executable.jar

Comment: But what about the plugins which I use from eclipse? Here is exactly my question, if I generated my code as an executable jar, then I can't call the plugins which I use from eclipse. I hope that I could make it clear!